# Plot not offsetting off the screen

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know what part of the code is making the plot not centered? It seems to be cutting it off at the side. I've researched and a temporary solutions was adjusting the `figsize` but this isn't a long terms solution. I've also tried adding space above without success.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def _invert(x, limits):
    """inverts a value x on a scale from
    limits[0] to limits[1]"""
    return limits[1] - (x - limits[0])

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    inverts if the scale is reversed"""
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)
    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    if x1 > x2:
        d = _invert(d, (x1, x2))
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    sdata = [d]
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        if y1 > y2:
            d = _invert(d, (y1, y2))
            y1, y2 = y2, y1
        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) 
                     * (x2 - x1) + x1)
    return sdata

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("on")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel,
                         angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

# example data
variables = ("NPG", "AP90", "Inverted 2", 
            "Normal Scale 2", "Normal 3", "Normal 4 %", "Inverted 3 %")
data = (1.76, 1.1, 1.2, 
        4.4, 3.4, 86.8, 20)
ranges = [(0.1, 2.3), (1.5, 0.3), (1.3, 0.5),
         (1.7, 4.5), (1.5, 3.7), (70, 87), (100, 10)]            
# plotting
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data)
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)
plt.savefig('radar-chart.png', facecolor='white')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save uncut figure use:

`plt.savefig('radar-chart.png', facecolor='white', bbox_inches='tight')`

Your problem occurs in `__init__` when axises are created.

Add to plot section of main this code and try:

```
# plotting
width, height = matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']
size = min(width, height)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(size*1.5, size))
```